How to install VPN on Linux Debian so that it could be used by built-in Windows 10 client?
What is nowadays recommended solution to setup VPN server on Linux Debian (Linux Wonderland 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.289-2 (2023-08-08) x86_64) so that I could use it with Windows 10 built-in VPN client?
I looked in the links provided at the What VPN server can I install on linux and connect to on Windows through its builtin VPN client?, but it is 10 years old and guides are obsolete (like to use no longer supported openswan).
I looked at the www.strongswan.org, but I can't see straightforward manual how to setup a server so that it could be used by Windows Build-in VPN Client.
I already have installed OpenVPN on Linux and can use it through OpenVPN on Windows, so it works, but if there is a way to use build-in Windows VPN client with OpenVPN server, OpenSwan server or better one, please help with some hints.

Did you check the strongSwan docs?

@ecdsa, thank you for the link. This is exactly what I was looking for. Am I correct that I need only two actions: (1) Enable Strong Key Exchange on Windows and (2) Put strongSwan Configuration for Windows Machine Certificates. Have I missed something ?

Depends on the client authentication method you want to use. If you use machine certificates, you have to distribute certificates to all clients. If you use username/password authentication and a server certificate from an already trusted CA (e.g. Let's Encrypt), you don't need to install any additional certificates on the clients.

@ecdsa, I use certificates and already installed them on the client PC to test. Should I just pass the two steps above? Should it be enough?
